# Node.Js promises and async/await

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, async-await

I am trying to use a oai-pmh harvester to harvest all articles from oai repositor and store them in a local mongo database. 
I have a small demo.js file to test and print the titles on the console and it works perfectly. This is my demo.js file:

```
const oaipmh = require('./my_modules/harvester/harvester.js');
const urlProvider='any OAI URL repo';    // change URL here

let harvester=new oaipmh.Harvester(urlProvider);

harvester.harvest(processItem,function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});

Function processItem(item){
    try{
        let titles=item.metadata['oai:dc:dc']['dc:title'];
        let title=(typeof titles=='object')?titles.join("\n"):titles;
        console.log(title);
        console.dir(item.metadata['oai_dc:dc']);
    }catch(err){
        // handle errors here
    }
};
```

I am still trying to learn how to use promises and async/await and how to handle it. So far I have tried to use it inside my controller, but I am getting an error.

On my router file i have:

```
router.route('/doc')
    .get(doc.aggregate_one);
```

On my controller file i have:

```
var Doc=require('../models/docModel);
const aoipmh=require('../../harvester/harvester');

exports.aggregate_one = async (req,res,next) => {
    const urlProvider = req.header('url');
    let harvester=new oaipmh.Harvester(urlProvider);

    harveste.harvestAsync(urlProvider,processItemmfunction(err,res){
    // do something
    });
};
```

I want to send the URL in the header of my get instead of the barcode. When I am trying to test the GET I am receiving an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error; Unexpected  status code 400 (expected 200)`

How can I use the example of the demo.js file inside my controller in order to handle the Promise?

Comment: There's not enough code shown here.  Don't see the code for `harveste.harvestAsync()` or `processItemmfunction()` so can't follow the code flow from `doc.aggregate_one()`.  Also, don't see any code where you're attempting to use `await`.